# Datatables - pagination and filtering not working when img tags are used

Tags: datatables

Say for example we have a table with `img` tags inside:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover" id="my-table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Icons</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Some Name</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#"><img src="some.png"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And in JS:

```
$('#my-table').DataTable({"ordering": false});
```

When there are lots of table rows, pagination nor filtering input field does show up. And all table rows appear in the same page.

Table works fine without the `img` tags.

I'm using `dataTables.bootstrap.min.js` with `jquery.dataTables.min.js`

Comment: Please show how you initialize the table as well.

Comment: @davidkonrad ohh forgot that. please see the updated post